# Magnific popup inline! With animate.css

Tags: jquery

i am very new to Jquery and could do with some help!

I have got my animate.css working with magnific popup IMAGE gallery but now i would like it to work on the INLINE gallery. This is the code i have

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pop-up-image').magnificPopup({
      removalDelay: 300,
      gallery:{enabled:true},
      type: 'image',
            image: {
            verticalFit: true,
            markup: '<div class="mfp-figure">'+
                '<figure>'+
                    '<div class="mfp-header">'+
                        '<div class="mfp-top-bar">'+
                            '<div class="mfp-title"></div>'+
                            '<div class="mfp-counter"></div>'+
                            '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="mfp-content-container">'+
                        '<div class="mfp-img"></div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="mfp-footer">'+
                        '<figcaption class="mfp-figcaption">'+
                            '<div class="mfp-bottom-bar-container">'+
                                '<div class="mfp-bottom-bar">'+
                                    '<div class="mfp-description"></div>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</figcaption>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</figure>'+
            '</div>'
        },  
          
   callbacks: {
    
      beforeOpen: function() {
        this.st.image.markup = this.st.image.markup.replace('mfp-figure', 'mfp-figure animated ' + this.st.el.attr('data-effect'));
      },
  
      markupParse: function(template, values, item) {
        values.title = item.el.attr('title'); 
      },
   
      beforeClose: function() {
        this.content.addClass('zoomOut');
      }, 
    
      close: function() {
        this.content.removeClass('zoomOut');
      },
            
    },

    });
  });
```

How do i get it to work with inline popup the same way as it does with the code above but with INLINE? What do i change?

Thank you.

Comment: this example will help you https://codepen.io/haimingpro/pen/MwQKyL

Comment: thenk you for the reply, I know how to use it for the image but not for the inline. That didnt help.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the reply but thats not what im asking for. I want to use with the inline type.

$('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
**type:'inline',**
midClick: true // Allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source in href.
});

Answer (score 1):

i got it working but how to a get the backgrroung now to anamate with it?

```
$('.website-project-popup').magnificPopup({
    type: 'inline',
    fixedContentPos: false,
    fixedBgPos: true,
    overflowY: 'auto',
    closeBtnInside: true,
    preloader: false,
    midClick: true,
    removalDelay: 500,
    gallery:{enabled:true},
    
    callbacks: {
        
        
    beforeOpen: function() {
        this.st.mainClass += 'animated ' + this.st.el.attr('data-effect');
    },
        
    beforeClose: function() {
        this.content.addClass('animated zoomOut');
    },

    close: function() {
        this.content.removeClass('animated zoomOut');
    },
        
        
      },
});
```